# Track number missing after iPhone upgrade to iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, music

Before the upgrade to IOS 8.4, when I was listening to music, it would have the track number at the top of the screen (i.e. "1 of 14") but with 8.4 I can't seem to find a way to put that back on, if it's even possible.  Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has removed the track number feature from the Music app and it is not known if or when it will return.

Answer (score -1):

When there are more than 15 new and excellent changes in the new music app and great upgrades still waiting, no one is caring for a option which shows track number.

The Apple Music doesn't have the track number feature because it can then update Albums with no remix tracks.

Every album has got some songs and they also add some remixed versions of the songs to the album itself.Some call them as Deluxe versions while some add them in original album as well.

In Apple music, at present doesn't allow the remixed tracks to be streamed ( maybe later ) So in order to not have a contradiction with the Track number, they removed the option.